# Django show Graphs with ChartJS

Tags: javascript, django, chart.js

I need to do a graph with ChartJs from my Expenses.

This is my view

```
@login_required
def index(request):
    truncate_month = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'date_reg')
    expense = Expense.objects.extra({'month': truncate_month}).values('month').annotate(Sum('total_amount'))
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', {"expense": expense})
```

On my template

```
{{ expense }}
```

And It shows the data in the following format:

```
[{
   'month': '2015-12-01',
   'total_amount__sum': 900.0
}, {
   'month': '2016-01-01',
   'total_amount__sum': 19334.0
}]
```

How can I format that data to be compatible with chartjs?

ChartJs Example:

```
labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"], //Here the month
datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40] //here 'total_amount__sum'
    },
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As bryanph said use Values_list, and then to change the quotes from ASCII you need to escape them in the template. You can use the safe filter.

Line in View:
    expenses = expense.values_list('month', flat=True)

Template:

```
{{ expense|safe }}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12193670)

Comment: Hi Steve, I edited the post, sorry was my first time actually answering on stack overflow. I had the same issue and bryanph answer and Carlos's comment help me come up to the full solution.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at values_list:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

This gives you lists of values rather than dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks bryanph

I did what you suggested.

In my view: 
expenses = expense.values_list('month', flat=True)

And now the browser shows 
['2015-12-01', '2016-01-01'] 

That's great. But the graph doesn't work because the quotes are printed in Ascci (&#39):
  labels: [(&#39;2015-12-01&#39;,), (&#39;2016-01-01&#39;,)],

How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to hook up [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck):

```
return render(request, 'home/index.html', json.dumps({"expense": expense}))
```

in the template:

```
data = JSON.parse({{ expense|safe }});

var labels = _.pluck(data, 'month');
var data = _.pluck(data, 'total_amount__sum');
```